# How to get the class name of a dropped item with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have few containers and few items. I want to drag an item into a container and get the class name of the dropped item.

Getting a class name is very easy `.className` but is not working

This is some code that I am working with (the `places[i]` is part of a loop so I did not include the entire code for the sake of clarification):

```
places[i].addEventListener('drop', function(e){
  console.log(this.childNodes[0].className  );
});
```

This does not work, the error is "Cannot read property 'className' ". I tried just `this.childNodes` and I get:

```
[item: function]
  0: div.coins.blue
    ....
    className: "coins blue"
    ...
```

I did try `this.childNodes['item']` logged `function item() { [native code] }`. Don't know where to go from here

here is a the basic code http://jsbin.com/wadavuci/1/edit?js,console,output

Thanks

Comment: Try `this.children[0].className`?

Comment: @EdCottrell It's not working in fiddle! the code is too complex maybe

Comment: @dfsq Yes, I get the same error of "can not read property className

Comment: How about `this.childNodes['item'][0].className`?

Comment: @EdCottrell same error!

I'm only using Js no library at all

Comment: even `this.childNodes['item'][0]` is undefined

Comment: This is really hard to fix without more code and/or a fiddle. Please try to produce some minimal version of your code that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: @EdCottrell this is the basic code. everything else I tried to add through up errors. If you drag the red ball to the gray area you'll see `function item() { [native code] }` in the console http://jsbin.com/wadavuci/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Based on the jsbin example you provided, `this.className` will do the trick where you have `this.childNodes[0].className`. If that is what you are looking for, please let me know, and I'll make this an answer.

Comment: @EdCottrell No I want the balls class name, the one that is dropped in. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @EdCottrell Each ball has a class of "red" or "blue", so I need to know which ball is dropped in the slots provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using drag-and-drop you must set manually set the data to transfer in the `dragstart` event. The data is set using the `setData()` member of the `dataTransfer` object of the event:

```
for (var i=0; i<coins.length; i++) {
    coins[i].addEventListener('dragstart', function(e){
        e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", this.className);
    });
}
```

Similarly, you must read the transferred data in the `drop` event:

```
for (var i=0; i<places.length; i++) {   
    places[i].addEventListener('drop', function(e){
        console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));
    });
    /* ... */
};
```

The [Native HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) article on http://www.html5rocks.com/ provides a nice walk through of how to handle drag-and-drop.

Comment: aha, I get that, I did use setData for the id name, but I did not think to do it for this. Thanks